# Losing the label column while doing aggregate function on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, group-by

I've been trying to do aggregate function on a dataframe that consist of number and string. While doing the aggregate function, I realize that the string data is missing. I want to keep the string data (label) as I need it to label the result of aggregation. Here is what I've coded :

```py
    def function (df) :
      l_dfrange = []
      step = 10
      gr = df.groupby(['label'], as_index=False)
      l_grouped = list(gr)
      for i in range(len(l_grouped)):
        df_range = pd.DataFrame(l_grouped[i][1])
        df_range["ID"] = np.arange(len(df_range))//step
        df_range = df_range.groupby("ID").agg([np.mean, np.std])
        l_dfrange.append(df_range)
    
      return l_dfrange, df_range
```

Initial dataframe :

```py
        gyro_x gyro_y gyro_z label
    1   0.05   0.05   0.6    jump
    2   0.03   0.03   0.6    jump
    3   0.02   0.04   0.6    jump
    4   0.08   0.09   0.6    stand
    5   0.03   0.03   0.6    stand
    6   0.02   0.04   0.6    stand
    7   0.05   0.05   0.6    jump
    8   0.03   0.03   0.6    jump
    9   0.02   0.04   0.6    jump
```

Result that I want :
Note that for the example, i limit the group to only consisted of 3 rows each group, and they were sorted by label and ID to indentify the group

```py
        gyro_x gyro_y gyro_z label ID
    1   0.05   0.05   0.6    jump  1
    2   0.03   0.03   0.6    jump  1
    3   0.02   0.04   0.6    jump  1
    7   0.05   0.05   0.6    jump  2
    8   0.03   0.03   0.6    jump  2
    9   0.02   0.04   0.6    jump  2
    4   0.08   0.09   0.6    stand 3
    5   0.03   0.03   0.6    stand 3
    6   0.02   0.04   0.6    stand 3
```

The end result that i want

```py
    ID  mean_gyro_x std_gyro_x mean_gyro_y std_gyro_y label
    1   0.05        0.05       0.6         0.6        jump
    2   0.05        0.05       0.6         0.6        jump
    3   0.03        0.03       0.6         0.6        stand
```

I combine first 3 rows in the example to get the aggregate result but also keeping the label (as they have been grouped by their label before). Is there any way I could keep the label? Also can I change the type to data frame? When I turn the `l_dfrange` into dataframe, it always return with feature name (columns), but no data.

Comment: Do you need change `df_range.groupby("ID").agg([np.mean, np.std])` to `df_range.groupby("label").agg([np.mean, np.std])` ? Or `df_range.groupby(["ID", label"]).agg([np.mean, np.std])` ? Why is missing ID columnin input data?

Comment: No, i have the result i needed from my code, but the label is missing from the result. i have to group it again by "ID" as i need to limit only 10 activities with the same label per group.

Answer (score 0):

created tmp.csv as follows:

```
gyro_x,gyro_y,gyro_z,label
0.05,0.05,0.6,jump
0.03,0.03,0.6,jump
0.02,0.04,0.6,jump
0.08,0.09,0.6,stand
0.03,0.03,0.6,stand
0.02,0.04,0.6,stand
```

pythonic style and pandas is very cool as you can see below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv')
print(df)
df = df.groupby('label').agg({'gyro_x': ['mean', 'std'], 'gyro_y': ['mean', 'std']}).reset_index()
df.columns = ['label', 'mean_gyro_x', 'std_gyro_x', 'mean_gyro_y', 'std_gyro_y']
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   gyro_x  gyro_y  gyro_z  label
0    0.05    0.05     0.6   jump
1    0.03    0.03     0.6   jump
2    0.02    0.04     0.6   jump
3    0.08    0.09     0.6  stand
4    0.03    0.03     0.6  stand
5    0.02    0.04     0.6  stand
   label  mean_gyro_x  std_gyro_x  mean_gyro_y  std_gyro_y
0   jump     0.033333    0.015275     0.040000    0.010000
1  stand     0.043333    0.032146     0.053333    0.032146
```

Comment: the problem is i'm going to extract a lot more than just mean and std. There were approx 90 columns by the end of the result and i don't think naming every one of the columns would be efficient?
I've only use mean and std as an example.
Also, i need to group it not just by the label, but also limiting the number of rows in every group with the same label

Comment: He will still not have access to the group by column after aggregation I am facing this problem and need a solution.